# How to shuffle collage images using jquery-collagePlus?

Tags: jquery, css, image, image-processing, plugins

I am developing a website in which i am using jquery-collagePlus plugin to make image collages . I want to make shuffling images dynamically when click on shuffle button. 
any one have solution for this (or any other method to do this) then kindly let me know ?

Here is My Demo [Collage Test](http://collage.bluecoresys.com/testcollage/examples/example.html)

here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $('.Collage').collagePlus({
        'targetHeight'    : 300,
        'fadeSpeed'       : "slow", 
        'effect'          : 'default',
        'direction'       : 'vertical',
        'allowPartialLastRow'       : false
     });
    $('.Collage').removeWhitespace().collagePlus(); 
});
```

//Html

```
<input name="shuffl" value="shuffle" type="button">
<section style="width:700px; " class="Collage effect-parent">
    <img src="../support/images/ed-lea-dribbble-2.png">
    <img src="../support/images/ed-lea-dribbble-3.png">
    <img src="../support/images/ed-lea-dribbble-4.png">
    <img src="../support/images/ed-lea-dribbble-6.png">
    <img src="../support/images/ed-lea-dribbble-1.png">
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this **[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kLQZ/)**

You can use **[this little pluggin](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-dom-elements/)** to shuffle DOM elements :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
           });
        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });
        return $(shuffled);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then put your `collagePlus`code into a function :

```
function refreshCollagePlus() {
    $('.Collage').collagePlus({
        'targetHeight'    : 300,
        'fadeSpeed'       : "slow", 
        'effect'          : 'default',
        'direction'       : 'vertical',
        'allowPartialLastRow'       : false
    });
}
```

And just do this on DOM ready :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#shuffle').on('click', function(){
        $('.Collage img').shuffle();
        refreshCollagePlus();
    });
    refreshCollagePlus();
});
```

The idea here is to init once the `collagePlus` plugin, and then `shuffle` the images and "refresh" the `collagePlus` plugin on the `#shuffle` button `click` event.

**EDIT : Prevent an image to move**

The cleanest and easiest way to achieve that is to give an image a specific class :

```
<img class="dontMove" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" />
```

And change this line :

```
$('.Collage img').shuffle();
```

to this :

```
$('.Collage img:not(.dontMove)').shuffle();
```

In this case, all the images having the class `dontMove` will always stay where they are, meanwhile others will randomly move.

Comment: awesome! but this shuffle is random ,actually i am looking for a custom random shuffle , means i wand to put 1 particular image at center of attraction called Hero Image.when user click on shuffle Hero image always be in center of attraction. can you add this functionality in this code ?

Comment: You should have said that in your question, I'll try to make some changes in the plugin.

Comment: good ! when i am doing this my hero image is looking small and other images looking big ,how could i put this Hero Image at last in queue means if any one select Hero image then it stood at <img src="../support/images/ed-lea-dribbble-1.png"> position so that always this image look big in size .

Comment: I think this is another question. But if I understand well, you could `.clone()` the image and `appendTo()` it to your `section`. Then remove it.

Comment: awesome! Brewal You are great your answer solved my problem i really appreciate your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41929/discussion-between-ammu-and-brewal)